# Allow specific SIP connection FreePBX

Tags: asterisk, sip, trunk, freepbx

Hey I am using FreePBX with firmware: 5.211.65-14 and service pack 1.0.0.0

On this asterisk server I have everything up and running, but inbound phone calls might be rejected:

```
WARNING[56522][C-00000ba4]: Ext. s:6 @ from-sip-external: "Rejecting unknown SIP connection from xxx.xx.x.xx
```

I talked to my service provider and they said this happens because they use a sip proxy, so my trunk may have connected to server A, but an incomming phone call might be offered by server B.
In this case it is rejected.

Now I am trying to find a solution for this problem, but could not find one so far.
I tried setting the 'insecure' to very.
I tried adding the ip's of both servers in the whitelist of the firewall.
I added the ip's of both servers in the peer details using 'permit='

Do you know how to allow both ip's while connected to just one of those?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So I found out that the SIP Provider is using two servers for the inbound phone calls. This is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to connect to every voip server they have and then adjust your internal routes. There is nu other way to do this. 
If you don't do this, asterisk might connect to Server A and get a response from server B.
He would deny server B.

In my case I set up two connections, one to server A and one to server B.
If any of the servers now respondes, Asterisk will accept.

Answer (score 0):

You have put all provider's server as trunks or allow guest access.